# Firefox Developer Edition [and others] not opening in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, firefox, catalina

Ok... tell me it's not just me, when I launch Firefox Developer Edition [68.0b13] in macOS Catalina [beta 2] I get the error message that it can't open because it's from an unidentified developer.

So, I try to go to the file in Application and right-click open and confirm that I want to open.  The base program opens but there is an updater sequence that Firefox tries to open that hits the same wall as before.

I've even gone to Security and Privacy and told it to open anyway.  Still nothing.

Does anyone know how to overcome this and get FDE to launch or am I just screwed until Apple and Mozilla figure their stuff out?

Comment: It is a beta - ask on the Apple beta forums

Comment: Doing that too. :)

Comment: Two unreleased beta software versions don't work well together.  It's to be expected.  Have you reported this on the Mozilla bug reporter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok... I figured it out.

Disable the block

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

Launch Firefox and allow the update to complete then re-enable the block.  I bet this will also resolve other software not opening as well.

```
sudo spctl --master-enable
```

Thanks to @Mark for the reminder about the Beta forums.

Comment: love you guys I had the same problem with firefox and whatsapp. problem solved thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Firefox 67.0.4. Catalina refused to recognise Mozilla so I downloaded of an earlier version Firefox (66) from the Mozilla site and replaced the latest version in Applications. It then worked fine. Firefox then updated to 67.0.4 and continued working fine

Answer (score 1):

in catalina beta 5 (shipped yesterday) issue is even higher, firefox (release, beta, nightly) does not work at all! steps:
1. clean every single dependency
2. install latest and greatest, clean install
3. start firefox

expected:
should run fine
actual:
you see main window, as soon as you click anywhere, exception occurs, application would not run at all, you are (of course) shown the error reporting dialog, but nothing beyond that

Comment: again, just making sure, with new beta 5, firefox is dead in the water and unlike before, this is not about creating a child process for update, it does not work at all anymore. apple is obviously smoking, i suspect that mongodb 32bit is deprecated, no 32bit processes are allowed (which is beyond stupid, it is fascist)